# Wifi Intel AC 3165 Yoga 700-14ISK, does not work with ubuntu

Tags: iwlwifi

I am trying to solve my Wifi Adapter Intel AC 3165 problem, I read and tried all the question and answers and nothing worked. 
I downloaded all the drivers at intel website and also tried to replace all of the for the 3165-9 and 3165-12 and 3165-13 as said in other posts. 
Any ideal on what should I try next?
Following is some information about my computer

mylaptop:~$ uname -r

4.2.0-040200rc8-generic

mylaptop:~$ rfkill list

```
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

mylaptop:~$ dmesg |grep iwl

```
[    1.690373] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    1.697517] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: loaded firmware version 15.195093.0 op_mode 
iwlmvm
[    1.721817] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 
3165, REV=0x210
[    1.721983] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[    1.722670] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[    1.832282] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-s'
[    1.837538] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0 wlp1s0: renamed from wlan0
```

mylaptop:~$ ls /lib/firmware | grep 7265

```
iwlwifi-7265-10.ucode
iwlwifi-7265-12.ucode
iwlwifi-7265-13.ucode
iwlwifi-7265-14.ucode
iwlwifi-7265-15.ucode
iwlwifi-7265-16.ucode
iwlwifi-7265-17.ucode
iwlwifi-7265-8.ucode
iwlwifi-7265-9.ucode
iwlwifi-7265D-10.ucode
iwlwifi-7265D-12.ucode
iwlwifi-7265D-13.ucode
iwlwifi-7265D-14.ucode
iwlwifi-7265D-15.ucode
iwlwifi-7265D-16.ucode
iwlwifi-7265D-17.ucode
iwlwifi-7265-ucode-25.30.14.0.tgz
```

mylaptop:~$ ls /lib/firmware | grep 3165

```
iwlwifi-3165-12.ucode
iwlwifi-3165-13.ucode
iwlwifi-3165-9.ucode
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your wireless adapter is blocked by `ideapad_laptop` module. You can disable it by running in terminal:

```
sudo modprobe -r ideapad_laptop
sudo rfkill unblock all
```

To get it to survive reboots run also:

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ideapad.conf <<< "blacklist ideapad_laptop"
```

P.S. And I do not recommend using mainline kernels. Kernel 4.2 is available in official repositories for Ubuntu supported version.

This issue is already fixed in the newest kernels but not backported to 4.2 yet.

Comment: It worked perfectly! 
Thank you!

I just correct my kernel version. 
Thank you.