# 500S-14ISK no Wifi interface

Tags: wireless

Sorry to throw a question with such little information.

Hardware: 
Overall - 500S-14ISK Laptop (ideapad) [specs](http://support.lenovo.com/hk/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/500-series/500s-14isk/80q3/007hhh?linkTrack=Caps%3ABody_SerialNumber&beta=false)
Wifi Card - I'm very keen to find out but the manufacturer seemed to let out little information, so I'm keen to find out what is it exactly. I think it is Broadcom. here's a link to its windows driver [link](http://drivers.softpedia.com/get/NETWORK-CARD/Broadcom/Lenovo-IdeaPad-500S-14ISK-Broadcom-WLAN-Driver-7352952-for-Windows-10-64-bit.shtml)

Software: fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

I'm taking notes from [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/737803/wifi-intel-ac-3165-yoga-700-14isk-does-not-work-with-ubuntu) but not sure how to start - total newbie here.

I'm also trying to use [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers) but `lspci -nn` actually showing a network controller as Qualcomm Atheros Device, with no wireless device insight it has [168c:0042] (rev 30) labeled.

So appreciate any help I can get and I'm more than happy to post any diagnostics here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Should have researched further before asking the question.

I found the answer in [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/708061/qualcomm-atheros-device-168c0042-rev-30-wi-fi-driver-installation).

The accepted answer can solve the problem for Ubuntu 16.04 as well.